# Custom GitHub badges with dynamic color

Tags: json, github, colors, badge, shields.io

I struggle with creating a [shields.io](https://shields.io) badge which changes color dynamically.

I am able to use the JSON response to parse a text into a [badge](https://img.shields.io/badge/dynamic/json.svg?label=custom&url=https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts&query=$[1].id&colorB=orange) and set the color to orange:

```
https://img.shields.io/badge/dynamic/json.svg?label=custom&url=https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts&query=$[1].id&colorB=orange
```

[image]

Works well...

---

However, I want to change the color according to a rule. I might return the HEX color in JSON as well to be parsed into the badge. I tried the public [API](http://www.colr.org/json/) to get a random color and ***test*** the behavior:

```
http://www.colr.org/json/color/random
```

I get the first randomly get color with JsonPath `$.colors[0].hex` and place it o the badge URL as both as the dynamic value and color:

```
https://img.shields.io/badge/dynamic/json.svg?label=custom&url=http://www.colr.org/json/color/random&query=$.colors[0].hex&colorB=$.colors[0].hex
```

Regardless of the randomly chosen color, the result is always somehow green (the last generated result was `#D0BB79`:

[image]

I would expect something like this which correctly matches the [`#D0BB79`](https://www.color-hex.com/color/d0bb79) color:

[image]

How to make the color dynamic as well? The sample dynamically colorful badges are provided with [Coveralls.io](https://coveralls.io/), [Codecov.io](https://codecov.io/) or [SonarCloud.io](https://sonarcloud.io/).

Comment: The discussions here may be of interest, in particular the new endpoint badge: https://github.com/badges/shields/issues/1752 ;)

Comment: @Pyves: Nope, I still wait for the answer even this is not urgent though. If you provide the short summary with an example as an answer and I gladly accept it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar trouble, and ended up using a command line tool called [anybadge](https://pypi.org/project/anybadge) which takes thresholds as parameters. This allows you to generate a badge with dynamic color in one command:

```sh
anybadge -l pylint -v 2.22 -f pylint.svg 2=red 4=orange 8=yellow 10=green
```

[image]

Colors can be defined by hex color code or a pre-defined set of color names.

The main difference here is that this isn't done by referencing a URL, so can't be embedded in the same way. I use this in my CI pipeline to generate various badges, then store them as project artifacts and reference them in my project `README.md`.